# MassTransit's Subscription Service is a single point of failure

Tags: msmq, soa, masstransit

I'm trying to configure MassTransit over MSMQ. I need to use the subscription service as I can't use Multicast because:

- I'm communicating over more than 1 subnet and
- I need persistent subscriptions

What I don't understand is why is the system designed so that if the subscription service isn't running, you can't initialize a bus instance.  After a delay you get "Timeout waiting for subscription service to respond".

I thought that goes against the idea of message queuing, that the message are held until the receiver is available. I thought communication with subscription service was done via the mt_subscriptions queue and startup wouldn't be dependent on the subscription service running.

Comment: has there been any resolution to this'? im dealing the same issue

Comment: I gave up on mass transit and moved to nservicebus, so I can't give you guidance. Sorry

Comment: how has your experience been with that?

Comment: Good. It's a commercial product, but the support infrastructure is worth every penny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the subscription service is how you persist and manage the subscriptions. If that's not running then there's no way to tell a message where it should be routed. It's also the only place where the storage of subscriptions happens. If you want, you can do static routing, manually configuring everything. But at the end of the day, MSMQ requires additional infrastructure for pub/sub. There's no way around that.

The reason you see a timeout, is that when MT starts up it says "Hey, I'm over here, here are my consumers. What are they other consumers on the bus?" So the subscription service needs to respond in a timely manner to get that information back. If there's no subscription registered, it's not that the message is just help - it's lost.

If you want something easier, you'll have to go with RabbitMQ. You won't need the subscription service running since the exchange binding within RMQ takes care of that for you.

Comment: So if what you're saying is correct, then the subscription service is a single point of failure. Is there a way to run 2 subscription service instances in the same MassTransit infrastructure?

Comment: You have to run a windows cluster for fail over. It's the only way to handle it with MSMQ. Once your services are running, a subscription service failure just means no one new can enroll in the bus. Existing members will continue to run as long as they aren't stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely what is happening is that the message is being added to the queue like you suspected, but the error handling spits out that particular error message because it knows to expect a subscription service on the other end. Maybe the reason you can't initialize a bus instance is because it doesn't detect something else on the other end of the bus (subscription service) so it won't send the message.

Subscription service probably acts as the middleman and determines when/where to send the message. Therefore the subscription service needs to be running in order to queue the message within mt_subscriptions without an error.

Comment: Do you have any working knowledge of Masstransit, or are you just guessing?

Comment: I've used MSMQ in some of my applications, but not MassTransit. I've taken a look at MassTransit, and I think what I'm saying is right. It has to adhere to rules set forth in MSMQ because it's using MSMQ for communication. Based on my understanding of MSMQ is that it needs a subscription service to determine where to route the message, and when.